# What is in file_get_contents('php://input') when applied to an html form

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I have a general question regarding `file_get_contents('php://input')`. When this code applies to a `<form>` that is submitted for processing, what is actually returned?

This is in regards to some code I'm trying to follow and understand. There is no problem with the code, it works fine. I'm just curious.

Javascipt handles a click function on a form button. The javascript code then calls a `payment_ini.php` script, which has the `file_get_contents('php://input')`:

```
// Retrieve JSON from POST body 
$jsonStr = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonStr);
```

Will `$jsonObj` contain the names/values from the form that is being processed?  If the form has fields for `name`, `email`, `phone`, will they be in `$jsonObj`?

I've tried adding some logging/printout code in dev mode, but it either causes errors or it wont show.

Thanks for helping me see through the cobwebs.

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  `error_log("jsonStr: " . $jsonStr);` adds to my `error_log`.  It shows what is in in the `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Previously, I tried `error_log("jsonObj: " . $jsonObj);`, which did not like the object.

Thanks for looking